# Multiple scrollable elements with slimScroll

Tags: jquery, slimscroll

I use jquery slimScroll and I find it really useful, but unfortunately I have bumped into a problem with it.

So the problem in more detail is: if we use slimScroll with an item that has another item embedded, for which we also use slimScroll (that is slimScroll is used for both items), they do not function properly together – it is very difficult. Namely: the two items cannot be scrolled separately, in no way, not if we hover the mouse over it, nor if we click in it to make it active.
In the test page I have inserted a textarea (just type into it) which also behaves in a weird way with slimScroll.

I made a test page:
http://seven7.uw.hu/slimscroll/index.html

So I call the plugin on multiple elements like so:

```
$(".content").slimScroll({
  'size': '8px',
  'height': '450px'
});

$(".texta").slimScroll({
  'size': '8px'
});

$(".contentInsideDiv").slimScroll({
  'size': '8px'
});
```

As you can see from my test page sources, the content div includes the other elements.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code in your question.

Comment: This link works fine for me on Chrome, you can use the mousewheel and drag the bars... On IE, the scroll bars are overlapping (this is something to do with styling of your elements) but it does work - only the scroll wheel functionality is buggy, on Firefox just the scroll wheel is buggy but you can drag fine etc etc

Comment: Thank for replying, the problem is with the mouse wheel, you cannot scroll the two divs separately by only mouse.

Comment: To make this work (in firefox), you would probably have to modify the part of slimScroll responsible for scrolling with mouse wheel and add event.StopPropagation() there, so the scrolling stays limited to the inner div and doesn't affect the outer one.